# Running values for whole chart

Tags: reporting-services

I ran with a bit of a problem with SSRS and I would like to ask if you encountered this previously. The report requirement for the report is to show a graph that looks like this.[image]

What I did was I made a Category group for the date value and Series Group for the data shown in Red and Blue. The issue I am having is representing the line pointed in the picture. When I tried to do it in SSRS, it generates N times based on how data the Series Group has. See screenshot below:
[image]

[image]

My question is would it be possible to ignore the groupings in the expression formula or somewhere so that the running value for both of the series groups in one line?

Comment: This is a good question. I have never tried this but maybe it works. Try to use the dataset scope in your running value expression, like this: `=RunningValue(Fields!YourField.Value, Sum, "YourDataSetName")`

Comment: This could also help you maybe: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/74d9affc-ebf3-485c-988e-f28f7049b600/how-to-make-one-of-the-chart-ignore-series-grouping?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: @Strawberryshrub thanks for replying. I also tried doing dataset scope but it is only allowing me to use series or category group. I also went for the link earlier and that's where I got the idea to try it :D

Comment: Also, if you notice it, the start of the darker line in the image is where the darker line ends on the other side. This tells me that the RunningValue formula works but got screwed up due to the series being added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to do it on SSRS so I decided to do it in T-SQL instead. I added a column to be used as the value for the running table

```
WITH t as(
SELECT SUM(Value1) AS 'RunningValue',
[Date]
FROM Table1
WHERE [Group] IN ('Group1', 'Group2')
GROUP BY [Date]
)

SELECT 
x.*, t.RunningValue
FROM(
SELECT 
[Group],
[Date], 
[Description] AS [Description], 
SUM(Value1) AS Value1, 
SUM(Value2) AS Value2,
SUM(Value3) AS Value3
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [Date], [Group], [Description]
) x
CROSS APPLY t WHERE t.[Date] = x.[Date]
```

The downside of using this is that it is that it becomes expensive when the table grows as i am basically querying twice.

I also used the link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/74d9affc-ebf3-485c-988e-f28f7049b600/how-to-make-one-of-the-chart-ignore-series-grouping?forum=sqlreportingservices provided by @StrawberryShrub to hide the duplicate line in the graph. Thanks all!